# Boost Python basic example does not work

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

Trying the simplest Hello World example from [Boost Python Quick Start](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/index.html#tutorial.quickstart)

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
    return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

Compiling project on Windows using the following CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(hello_ext CXX)
set(TARGET hello_ext)

set(BOOST_MIN_VERSION "1.61.0")
set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.61.0" "1.61")
set(BOOST_ROOT ${MY_BOOST_DIR}) 

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)

find_package(PythonLibs 3.4 REQUIRED )
find_package(Boost 1.61.0 COMPONENTS python REQUIRED) 

file(GLOB SOURCES *.cpp)

include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

python_add_module(${TARGET} ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${TARGET} ${Boost_PYTHON_LIBRARY} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

The module compiled successfully as hello_ext.pyd. Trying to access it from the Python script placed in the same directory:

```
import hello_ext
print(hello_ext.greet())
```

Getting the following execution result:

> python3 test_cpp.py
>
> Import Error: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Also, tried to place the hello_ext.pyd to the Python DLL directory (C:/Python34/DLLs) with the same result

Windows 7 32 bit

C++ compiler: Visual C++ 2015

Python 3.4.2, Boost 1.61

Update: solved, see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a directory contained Boost Python *.lib and *.dll files to PATH. It makes the example work

Answer (score 0):

This is for mac users because I tried the above solution and it did not work for me using osx el capitan. I have two CMakeLists.txt that work, however, I do not think they are a problem based on, https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16335.

```
PROJECT(example)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set( CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON )
cmake_policy(SET CMP0042 NEW)
set(EIGEN_DIR "/usr/local/include/eigen3/" )
set(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS "//anaconda/include/python2.7")
set(PYTHON_LIBRARY "//anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.dylib")
find_package(Boost 1.66.0 COMPONENTS python)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${EIGEN_DIR} ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} include)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
    set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
    add_library (yay MODULE src/example_ext.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(yay ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARY})
endif()

PROJECT(example)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set( CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON )
cmake_policy(SET CMP0042 NEW)
set(EIGEN_DIR "/usr/local/include/eigen3/" )
find_package(Boost 1.66.0 COMPONENTS python3)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
    set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
    find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${EIGEN_DIR} ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} include)
    add_library (yay SHARED src/example_ext.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(yay ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARY})
endif()
```